# MIPS - is substring a part of string

Tags: mips

i should write MIPS code to check weather given string str contains substring part -> contains(char* str, char* part). I have written comments on almost every line how i approached it, but it does not work for all cases. For example:

**str = 'compilers'** and **part='omp'** it returns **0**

**str = 'compilers'** and **part='lers'** it returns **1**

It only works if part is sequence of last characters in str. I have been staring for an hour trying to find a mistake but failed.. appreciate the help!

```
.text

contains:
    move $t0, $a0 #copy of str address
    move $t1, $a1 #copy of part address
    loopContains:
        lb $t2, 0($t0) #str[t0]
        lb $t3, 0($t1) #str[t1]
        beqz $t2, exitDoesntContain #if str[t0] == '\0' doesnt contain
        bne $t2, $t3, goOn #if str[t0] != str[t1] load next char of str
        innerLoop: #if they are equal
            addi $t0, $t0, 1 #add 1 on address
            addi $t1, $t1, 1 #add 1 on address
            lb $t4, 0($t0) #load character of str
            lb $t5, 0($t1) #load character of part
            beqz $t5, exitDoesContain #if we are at the end of part, exit it contains substring
            beq $t4, $t5, innerLoop #if they are equal continue loop
        goOn: #if they are not equal, go on load next character of str and load start adress of part
            addi $t0, $t0, 1
            move $t1, $a1
            j loopContains
    exitDoesContain:
        li $v0, 1
        jr $ra
    exitDoesntContain:
        li $v0, 0
        jr $ra

main:
    la $a0, str
    li $a1, 50
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    la $a0, part
    li $a1, 50
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    la $a0, str
    la $a1, part

    jal contains

    move $a0, $v0

    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0,10
syscall

.data
    str: .space 50
    part: .space 50
```

Comment: You should load this code onto a mips simulator (e.g. Mars) and debug it step by step until you find where it deviates from what you expect.

Comment: Debugging a broken algorithm in assembly is hard when you don't know assembly and assembly debugging.  Make a working C version and then take that to assembly.  Otherwise, upgrade your debugging skills.  Code goes wrong at exactly one point, so find where it first goes wrong and fix that (then repeat)..

Comment: @ErikEidt I have managed to fix it using MARS :D, thanks everyone